# Swift pod in objective-c project issue

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, cocoapods

I tried to update a Pod that is in swift now.
So I added use_frameworks! into my Podfile and pod install.
I also checked "Embedded Content Contains swift Code" is YES

The error that my other pods that are in Objective-C cannot be found. (file not found)

If I understoof, use_frameworks compiles all pods as frameworks even the objective C ones that don't need that, but anyone can help me fix this issue ? 
Do I need to use a Bridging-Header ?

Answer (score 1):

When using frameworks with Swift pods, instead of using a bridging header, in the files that you wish to use the framework in, you just have to `import FrameworkName`